# Send an HTTP request to an Azure VM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, http, virtual-machine

I have built an HTTP server using C# and a frontend using React. They both work when using localhost.

Now I needed to move them both to Azure, so I created a VM to run the server first. The app runs, but the requests never arrive to the server. I was careful to make sure port 80 was open when creating the VM.

This is the code that initializes the http listener on the server (port is 80)

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:" + port.ToString() + "/");
listener.Start();
```

And this is the fetch request

```
let url = new URL("http://137.117.143.214:80");
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({
    t: "login",
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers(),
    mode: 'no-cors'
  });
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the url's?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I cannot get a response even with a simple "GET" by just putting the url in my browsers address bar... Are you sure it is running and configured properly?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was stopped, I was trying something. It's running now

Comment: I did. If I go to the network tab of my VM is shows port 80 is allowed

Comment: From my test it still closed from internet. Go to Network Watcher (search by this name), there is an option IP flow verify, run some test from there, select your VM, source IP, source Port, destination IP and so on, you can make sure that Azure is not blocking anything. Once from locahost your application works, it looks like a network issue for me. Is there firewall inside VM (Windows firewall or iptable Linux).

Comment: It was the windows firewall omg, I was so focused on the network settings I didn't even think of the simplest thing. Thank you so much man :)

Answer (score 1):

It was the windows firewall inside the VM blocking it